# What is the implication for convergence of MCMC if the Gelman-Rubin statistic increases again after initial convergence?

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, convergence

I am working on an MCMC sampler and in tests sometimes observe the following behavior of the Gelman-Rubin convergence diagnostic $R$.

1. Across the first $n$ samples I estimate $R$ after every $i$ iterations while always discarding half samples for 'burn-in'. Suppose $n$ is the point where $R$ first reaches a level below 1.1. This I call converged. For clarity: $R$ is computed using only the second half of the $n$ samples.
2. Then I sample an additional $r$ samples, so that the total number of samples after burn-in is (n/2 + r). I then observe $R$ sometimes increases again successively to substantially higher values $R>1.1$. This indicates that the MCMC chain has not converged although after the initial $n$ samples (while discarding $n/2$ samples before computing $R$) it had seemed converged.
3. When I continue sampling, $R$ will at some point again reach a level below 1.1.

**What are the implications for the usefulness of $R$ to assess convergence of the algorithm?**

The index $R$ is supposed to say something about the probability that the chain is converged. It compares the estimated total marginal posterior variance $T$ across chains (between plus within variance) to the pooled within variance $W$.

$$ R= \sqrt {T/W} $$

As a side-note I am sure I initialize the chains over-dispersed relative to the target posteriors so that in the beginning of the chains $T$ is an over-estimate of the posterior variance. But it converges to it. If both quantities $T$ and $W$ reach the same value we say that each chain probably has explored the whole posterior and $R$ approaches 1.

The behavior above seems to say that the total variance of the chain after $n$ samples (calculated on the second half of the samples) was not yet a good estimate of the total posterior variance. But this behavior then questions the whole usefulness of the statistic. Perhaps somebody can advise if I go wrong somewhere.

Comment: I would not 100% trust a convergence diagnostic to diagnose convergence! The assessment is quite relative to the domain explored so far by the chain(s). If they struggle to escape the attraction zone of a particular mode, the diagnostic may be quite optimistic for that reason, while a later escape may signal the existence of other modes. I thus advise to take these criteria as relative...

Comment: @Xi'an Thanks... so what to do to assess convergence? I was considering to use the upper bound of $R$ instead, as a conservative measure. By the way, it is for a monte carlo simulation study where I evaluate the algorithm. I need some 'objective' measure when to stop sampling that does need a human to take a decision.

Comment: My low-tech approach to convergence is to run the same MCMC (or ABC) algorithm 10 or 20 times and plot the marginal density estimators. If there is too much variability, I re-run it longer or else modify the algorithm or the prior.